# CS0120: An object reference is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

Getting this error when I submit my form to savetext.aspx action file:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get'
```

On this line:

```
string path = "/txtfiles/" + Request.Form["file_name"];
```

Whole code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<script runat="server">

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = "/txtfiles/" + Request.Form["file_name"];
        if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine(request.form["seatsArray"]);
            sw.WriteLine("");
            }   
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) 
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: `public static void Main()` in an ASPX page?! Hmm... Maybe you should explain what you are trying to do as I sense disturbance in the force.

Comment: Wouldn't you need 

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.Page" %>

Comment: To take the contents of an array (hidden form object "seatsArray") and put it into a text file named what the user put in "file_name". @MikeTWebb, that just generates another error: CS0138: 'System.Web.UI.Page' is a type not a namespace. Thanks

Comment: @Darin, @IceDragon....thanks. I was curious...

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Looking at the File.CreateText Method on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx), the example has "public static void Main()"? Thanks

Comment: @IceDragon, yeah in a console application. ASP.NET web application is a completely different beast. I would suggest you starting to read here: http://www.asp.net/get-started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this `Test` class as well as the static `Main` method and replace it with a `Page_Load` instance method like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        string path = "/txtfiles/" + Request.Form["file_name"];
        if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Request.Form["seatsArray"]);
                sw.WriteLine("");
            }   
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) 
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                Response.Write(s);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Also you probably want to output to the HttpResponse instead of a console in a web application. Another remark is about your file path: `"/txtfiles/"`, NTFS usually doesn't like such patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Darin Dimitrov gave you a hint in right direction, but i want just to give answer to question *why* does this error happen. Normal error should be:

> The name 'Request' does not exist in
>   the current context

This happen because for each `aspx` file a class is created that inherits from `Page` by default. All new classes defined inside `aspx` file become nested classes of that one. `Request` is member of class `Page` and this particular error happen because you try to access it from static method of nested type.